# merge the database query result based on date

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a database query result like this:

```
date        sum                              avg                            dist
2016-01-01  Decimal('11.0909090909090909')  Decimal('3.7272727272727273')   58.53545455
2016-05-01  Decimal('11.6666666666666667')  Decimal('4.0000000000000000')   74.87666667
```

How can I get the result as following:

```
date        sum                             avg                             dist
2016-01-01  Decimal('11.0909090909090909')  Decimal('3.7272727272727273')   58.53545455
2016-02-01  0                               0                               0
2016-03-01  0                               0                               0
2016-04-01  0                               0                               0
2016-05-01  Decimal('11.6666666666666667')  Decimal('4.0000000000000000')   74.87666667
2016-06-01  0                               0                               0
2016-07-01  0                               0                               0
2016-08-01  0                               0                               0
2016-09-01  0                               0                               0
2016-10-01  0                               0                               0
2016-11-01  0                               0                               0
2016-12-01  0                               0                               0
```

Thank you.

Comment: If what you're showing here is pandas dataframe, please edit your question and add the pandas tag.

Comment: Have you considered creating a dictionary for the months, then populating that from the database query. Print out the results from the updated dictionary.

Comment: I have  created an array for all the month and trying to display based on the condition checking,